# How to search in columns in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, unpivot, lateral-join

I have two table,the names table and the earnings table.

| Name_ID | Name_desc |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | mark |
| 2 | smith |
| 3 | becky |
| 4 | jimmy |

and the earnings table

| ID_1 | Earnings_1 | ID_2 | Earnings_2 | ID_3 | Earnings_3 | ID_4 | Earnings_4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 500 | 2 | 5454 | 3 | 1247 | 4 | 7844 |

You can try it out here:

https://dbfiddle.uk/d3a3rfG0

**Question: How to join Name_ID and ID_ to get the earnings. I need a funtion to check every ID column in the earnings table and if it match then get the earnings.**

The goal is a table that looks like this:

| Name_ID | Name_desc | earnings |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | mark | 500 |
| 2 | smith | 5454 |
| 3 | becky | 1247 |
| 4 | jimmy | 7844 |

Comment: "Who designs a table this way" - clearly someone who is still learning. Be easy with your words, @siggemannen, and try to help without being condescending.

Comment: Ok, good point. Op. You should think about the design. What happens when you need Earnings # 1000. SQL Server tables doesn't support unlimited number of columns. What's wrong with a ID, Earnings table instead

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend unpivoting the earnings table first in a lateral join, so we can then easily join it with the names, and aggregate:

```
select n.name_id, n.name_desc, sum(x.earnings) earnings
from earnings e
cross apply ( values 
    (e.id_1, e.earnings_1),
    (e.id_2, e.earnings_2),
    (e.id_3, e.earnings_3),
    (e.id_4, e.earnings_4)
) as x(id, earnings)
inner join names n on n.name_id = x.id
group by n.name_id, n.name_desc
order by n.name_id
```

The upside of this method is that it scans the table only once, as opposed to multiple `left join`s or `union`s, so it should perform more efficiently and scale better.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/rCGFvvgd)**

| name_id | name_desc | earnings |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | mark | 500 |
| 2 | smith | 5454 |
| 3 | becky | 1247 |
| 4 | jimmy | 7844 |

Answer (score 1):

What you think about this code. Look very simple:

```
SELECT Name_ID, Name_desc
  , COALESCE (  ( SELECT Earnings_1 FROM earnings as c WHERE   c.ID_1 = n.Name_ID )
             ,  ( SELECT Earnings_2 FROM earnings as c1 WHERE c1.ID_2 = n.Name_ID )
             ,  ( SELECT Earnings_3 FROM earnings as c2 WHERE c2.ID_3 = n.Name_ID )
             ,  ( SELECT Earnings_4 FROM earnings as c3 WHERE c3.ID_4 = n.Name_ID ) ) as earnings
FROM NAMES as n
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select n.Name_ID, n.Name_desc, 
       sum(coalesce(e1.Earnings_1, 0) +
           coalesce(e2.Earnings_2, 0) +
           coalesce(e3.Earnings_3, 0) +
           coalesce(e4.Earnings_4, 0)
       ) as earnings
from names n
left join earnings e1 on e1.id_1 = n.Name_ID
left join earnings e2 on e2.id_2 = n.Name_ID
left join earnings e3 on e3.id_3 = n.Name_ID
left join earnings e4 on e4.id_4 = n.Name_ID
group by n.Name_ID, n.Name_desc
```

#### [DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/84b__Y29)

Comment: a lot of code. What you think about my code see under

Comment: yes why, why you say it

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM Earnings
select n.*,e.Earnings_1 Earning from Names n inner join Earnings e on n.Name_ID=e.ID_1

union
select n.*,e.Earnings_2 Earning from Names n inner join Earnings e on n.Name_ID=e.ID_2

union
select n.*,e.Earnings_3 Earning from Names n inner join Earnings e on n.Name_ID=e.ID_3

union
select n.*,e.Earnings_4 Earning from Names n inner join Earnings e on n.Name_ID=e.ID_4
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote dynamic code for it. This code doesn't depend your count of id but you must sure that every name_id value exists in earnings table.

```
declare @columnlist nvarchar(max)=''
declare @table table(name_id int,earnings bigint)
  
SELECT @columnlist=@columnlist+' select ID_'+ cast(name_id  as nvarchar(10))+',Earnings_'+ cast(name_id  as nvarchar(10))+' from Earnings union all'
FROM NAMES



SELECT @ColumnList=Substring(@ColumnList, 1, Len(@ColumnList) - 10)

insert into @table
exec sp_executesql @columnlist

  select t.*,n.name_desc from @table t join names n on t.name_id=n.name_id
```